# I want to Pie chart animated at on load how I make it?(I am refer Google visualization API )

Tags: animation, google-visualization

I refer animation tag in option
option:{
animation:
{
startup:true,
duration:1500,
easing:'out'
}
}
but it not working for my code, please suggest me any other method to make pie chart animate.

Comment: animation simply isn't available on the [PieChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)...

Comment: Thanks for replay.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Dashboard.aspx/GetChartData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawChart(response.d);
                    }
            });
        })
        function drawChart(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'ColumnName');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]);
            }

            var options = {
                title: "All Complains Status",
                position: "top",
                fontsize: "14px",
                is3D: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                animation: {duration: 1000,easing: 'in',startup: true},
                slices: { 0: { color: '#8e3333' }, 1: { color: '#af4e13' }, 2: { color: '#46416f' }, 3: { color: '#319bb9' }, 4: { color: '#305b63' }, 5: { color: '#34733f' }, 6: { color: '#222d32' } }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))
            chart.draw(data, options);

            // initial value
            var percent = 0;
            // start the animation loop
            var handler = setInterval(function () {
                // values increment
                percent += 1;
                // apply new values
                data.setValue(0, 1, percent);
                data.setValue(1, 1, 100 - percent);
                // update the pie
                chart.draw(data, options);
                // check if we have reached the desired value
                if (percent > 74)
                    // stop the loop
                    clearInterval(handler);
            }, 20);
        }

    </script>
```